# Mouse input from files /dev/input

Tags: linux, mouse

My goal is to obtain mouse input on Linux. Right now I'm trying to obtain input from the files in `/dev/input`. On my specific system, I know that the file `/dev/input/event10` corresponds to my mouse, and returns EV_REL and EV_KEY events for the mouse input. However, I know that this is not universal, and that different `/dev/input/event#` files correspond to different devices. I'm aware of the file `/dev/input/mice`, but apparently this file is a ["hack for legacy systems"](https://docs.kernel.org/input/input.html), so I'm assuming its use is discouraged. The crux of my question comes down to determining which input event file/files correspond to the mouse. I've tried searching through `/proc/bus/input/devices` which gives the event file corresponding to the device, but outside of the word "mouse" in the name of the device, there seems to be no indication of what purpose it serves. Eg. Mouse, keyboard. All I've tried is obtaining input through these files, but if there is an alternative system in which to obtain the input, then I would be elated to hear about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a late response, but in case anyone stumbles upon this in the future, here is a summary of how to find a specific type of device on any Linux system (algorithmically).

Linux does not discriminate between mice, keyboards, gamepads, etc. An input device can, in theory, send any kind of event data and does not have to "conform" to the limits of a specific type. *However*, most real-world devices are obviously not like that. That's why sysfs provides information on what kind of data a device writes to its eventX file, which are called the device's "capabilities". Here is a summary of information about device capabilities:

`/sys/class/input/eventX/device/capabilities` contains 9 text files. `abs`, `ff`, `key`, `led`, `msc`, `rel`, `snd`, and `sw` correspond to "event types", which are documented [here](https://docs.kernel.org/input/event-codes.html#event-types). `ev` basically describes which of the other files contain non-zero data.

Each file contains ASCII hexadecimal characters, grouped into regions of 16, separated by spaces. The hex characters need to be read and decoded into binary from **right to left**. If a group contains less than 16 characters, the missing characters are implied to be 0 and need to be appended manually to the resulting binary.
Each bit in the binary data is a boolean flag that states whether or not the device can procude a certain [event code](https://docs.kernel.org/input/event-codes.html#event-codes).

**Example:** Can device X produce any KEY_ESC (escape key) events?

- Read `/sys/class/input/eventX/device/capabilities/key` as ASCII
- Decode characters to binary (as described above)
- Check the bit at zero-based index KEY_ESC (according to [input-event-codes.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h), KEY_ESC = 1)
- If the bit is 1, the device *may* send KEY_ESC events (i.e., it's probably a keyboard and can be eliminated from your mouse candidates). If the bit 0, then it will *never* send these events.

Mouse buttons are also encoded in `key`, even though their macros have the prefix `BTN`, so the approach is basically identical. What's also relevant in your case is the fact that mice are typically the only devices capable of sending `REL_<...>` events. You can find more information on that in the previously linked Linux kernel documentation.

It's a lot of work, yes, but it's universal and can give you a lot of clues about the hardware and its features.

Finally, [there is an even more detailed document on my GitHub](https://gist.github.com/TriceHelix/de47ed38dcb4f7216b26291c47445d99) in case anyone is interested.